# WPF filling a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm creating a WPF application with a `DataGrid`. I'd like some advice on the code I've written:

```
<DataGrid  Margin="0,10,10,10" LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow"    Name="user_view" EnableRowVirtualization="False" Grid.Column="2"    CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True"  CanUserResizeRows="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" 
    AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>          
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding name}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Width="*" Binding="{Binding surname}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Width="*" Binding="{Binding address}"></DataGridTextColumn>

 // and so on
 // and so on
 // and so on
```

...are all the cells that I bound my SQL View to.

Now, to fill the `DataGrid`:

```
public void LoadView()
{
    try
    {
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
        command.CommandText = MyApk.Properties.Resources.user_datagrid; 

        DataSet DST = new DataSet();
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        SQLiteDataAdapter SDA = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
        SDA.Fill(DT);
        this.user_view.ItemsSource = DT.AsDataView();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And the query to create the view is basically:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS user_details AS SELECT name,surname,address //more stuff here
```

The specific points I'd like addressed are:

1. Is this the right way to fill the `DataGrid`?
2. Is it hard coded?
3. How can I make it even better?

Comment: Does it work as wanted ?

Comment: Yes it does, but if its possible to "make" it more "flexible" as questions says.

Comment: I'm not posting full code because of the unnecessary data. The cells are almost the same, only `Name` and `Binding` changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> public void LoadView()
> {
>     try
>     {
>         SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
>         command.CommandText = MyApk.Properties.Resources.user_datagrid; 
>
>         DataSet DST = new DataSet();
>         DataTable DT = new DataTable();
>         SQLiteDataAdapter SDA = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
>         SDA.Fill(DT);
>         this.user_view.ItemsSource = DT.AsDataView();
>     }
>     catch (Exception ex)
>     {
>         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
>     }
> }
> ```

- `DataSet DST = new DataSet();` is never used and should be deleted.
- both `SQLiteCommand` and `SQLiteDataAdapter` are implementing `IDisposable` so you should enclose them in a `using` statement to automatically dispose them after their usage. In addition the constructor of the `SQLiteCommand` is overloaded to take a commandtext too.
- variables should be named using `camelCase` casing and shouldn't be named using abbreviations so `SDA` could simply be `dataAdapter` and `DT` will be `dataTable`.

Implementing the mentioned points will lead to

```
public void LoadView()
{
    try
    {

        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(MyApk.Properties.Resources.user_datagrid, connection))
        using (SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command))
        {            
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            this.user_view.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But now this is tightly coupled to the `user_view` control and the query `MyApk.Properties.Resources.user_datagrid` which is suboptimal.

If we pass an `ItemsControl` object and a `string` to this method it would be more flexible like so

```
public void LoadView(ItemsControl control, string commandText)
{
    try
    {

        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, connection))
        using (SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command))
        {            
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            control.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and can be called like

```
LoadView(this.user_view, MyApk.Properties.Resources.user_datagrid);
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you! And one questions...do you have any advice about XAML? Do I have to do again manual binding or?

Comment: No idea about XAML, sorry ( no I am not, I don't like GUI ).